# Matplotlib Navigation Toolbar: remove "Edit curves lines and axes parameters"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt, toolbar

Recently I began exploring developing UI in Qt Designer and editing them through PyQt.
Things have been going pretty smoothy, but I'm currently stuck trying to solve the following issue:

I've inserted a MatplotLib widget through Qt Designer and managed to plot pretty well horizontal bars using barh. Next I tried and successfully managed to insert a functional NavigationToolBar through matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.NavigationToolbar2QT

Then, following this thread (and similar ones) I managed to edit which buttons I would like to display on the toolbar... [How to modify the navigation toolbar easily in a matplotlib figure window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695678/how-to-modify-the-navigation-toolbar-easily-in-a-matplotlib-figure-window)

It works well for every button except for the last one, with a check box drawing which description "Edit curves line and axes parameters".
In this particular case, I would really like to remove this button, because it constantly resizes the plot when moving the mouse and in this case I don't need this button.

I haven't found yet any thread discussing this particular toolbar button (just this one [matplotlib: Qt4Agg toolbar's irritating bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445732/matplotlib-qt4agg-toolbars-irritating-bug))

The code used to insert the toolbar and currently edit buttons looks something like this:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT

class currentUI(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(currentUI,self).__init__()
        (...)
        uic.loadUi('portfolioManager.ui',self)
        self.initUI()
        (...)
    def initUI(self):        
        self.setWidgetsPropertiesAndActions()
    (...)
    def setWidgetsPropertiesAndActions(self):
        (...)
        self.navi_toolbar=NavigationToolbar(self.mplwidgetExposures, self)
        self.LayoutPlot.addWidget(self.navi_toolbar)
(...)
class NavigationToolbar(NavigationToolbar2QT):

    toolitems = [t for t in NavigationToolbar2QT.toolitems if
                 t[0] in ('Home','Pan', 'Zoom', 'Save','Subplots')]
```

This successfully embeds the toolbar, but the "edit" button remains.

Thanks very much for any insight.
Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove it by adding the following to your `NavigationToolbar` class

```
    actions = self.findChildren(QtGui.QAction)
    for a in actions:
        if a.text() == 'Customize':
            self.removeAction(a)
            break
```

The reason you can't remove this particular button by modifying `toolitems` is because it gets added to the toolbar separately after all the `toolitems` entries have been added.

```
    for text, tooltip_text, image_file, callback in self.toolitems:
        if text is None:
            self.addSeparator()
        else:
            a = self.addAction(self._icon(image_file + '.png'),
                                     text, getattr(self, callback))
            self._actions[callback] = a
            if callback in ['zoom', 'pan']:
                a.setCheckable(True)
            if tooltip_text is not None:
                a.setToolTip(tooltip_text)

    if figureoptions is not None:
        a = self.addAction(self._icon("qt4_editor_options.png"),
                           'Customize', self.edit_parameters)
        a.setToolTip('Edit curves line and axes parameters')
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your insights! Following your idea I generated a function within the NavigationToolbar subclass for removing actions and worked superb. Cheers!